# How to handle lifetime in firebase dynamic links ? (iOS)

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, app-store, firebase-dynamic-links

I have a question about `dynamic links` on iOS. We use them in our applications, and it seems that their expiration time is really short (about 5 minutes).

From the appstore, its not working because the download last more than this time
From xcode build, if we open directly the app its working. If we build from xcode and then wait 5 minutes, its not working anymore

Any clue about this ? Its really bad because Branch base lifetime is about 2hours, and a 5 minutes lifetime make them kind of useless

Comment: Can you be more clear about "It's not working anymore"? Is the link still directing people to your app? Are you no longer fetching any incoming link? Are you fetching the link but the library isn't parsing it correctly?

Comment: Is the link still directing people to your app? YES
Are you no longer fetching any incoming link? YEAP, that's the problem

Comment: Yep, as CedricSoubrie said, firebase lost the relation between the ipad and the initial download from the AppStore

Answer (score 4):

Ok, got the answer from support. I put it here for others people

*Hi Jonathan,*

*Yes, the 5 minutes limitation is intended.  I have brought your request to the attention of the engineers, but I can't share any details or timelines at this time.*

*Thanks,*

**EDIT:** As said Todd Kerpelman Firebase was super reactive and update the lifetime to 60 minutes. Work perfect now ! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Some further detail:

Yes, this 5 minute limitation was intentional as FeFe noted -- due to the way the Dynamic Links team is implementing this feature, the accuracy of dynamic links for non-installed apps tends to decrease over time, and they wanted to make sure there was good trade-off between time and accuracy.

That said, I think they went *too* far in the "accuracy" direction, and after some discussion, the team decided to change this limit to an hour. Note that this value isn't set in stone and might be subject to change in the future, depending on feedback from developers and users. But I think 60 minutes should be a pretty good setting for most people.