# When will a firebase dynamic link expire?

Tags: firebase

I'm trying to figure out how long I can use a Firebase dynamic link (small link). Because currently I am generating a link every time I need one.

I want to create one link and send it to hunderds of people. Is that possbile? What when someone wants to click on that specific link after 1 day/week/month/year? Can I use a link for all time? Or do I need to create a new link everytime I want to send it to someone?

Please help me out with this one.

Comment: Removed iOS related tags since this related only to Firebase. Fixed grammar and formatting.

Comment: This might help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43491846/how-to-handle-lifetime-in-firebase-dynamic-links-ios

Comment: @mark922 That can't be the case.. right? Because if I send a link to someone and that specific person wants to click on it 10 days later. Does it mean that this isn't possible? Also how many people can use 1 link? Becuase I want to regenerate one link and send it to hundreds of people.

Comment: I understand your concern. I will look into it and get back to you.

Comment: @mark922 Thank you!

Comment: @mark922 Hi Mark, have you found some usefull information? Hope to hear from you.

Comment: @IOSporgrammerIOS I don't think there is any expiry to the dynamic link as such. Your case might fall under the first one described here :  https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-links. You can create one-off links to share on social media or do other stuff.

Comment: @mark922 Hi Mark, thanks for your reply. I use the second method from the link you provided me. So the link is created dynamically. There still isnt a expiry you think? Hope to hear from you.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, dynamic links work for as long as your firebase project stays active. I have used some dynamic links for more than over a year after they were created.

I didn't see anything about time limits in the official documentation.

Comment: Please consider improving the wording of your answer. This is not very readable.

Comment: thanks @GhostCat for comment. I will edit my answer.