# Firebase dynamic links lifetime

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm using `Firebase dynamic links` to share links with some parameters between users. 
For now, I am using only an Android version, but I plan to extend my app to support iOS version.

I'm asking for help about:

- how long is the `lifetime` of `Firebase dynamic links`?
- what do you suggest me, should I store generated link to my `database` and later share it between users or generate a new link on every share (users can share the link for a same set of parameters several time, not only one time)

Thanks

Comment: May be you will get help from (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43491846/how-to-handle-lifetime-in-firebase-dynamic-links-ios)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Dynamic Links don't expire
2. I generally prefer adding a new link every share. It means you can do things like easily change or A/B test some of the parameters around the link (like the social sharing settings). It does mean you have to make a network call every time, but I guess the same would hold true for keeping your link in the database. For more info, you might want to check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LqCi-TaUfJs). (It's for iOS, but a lot of the principles are the same)